# How come Yuki Onna turn into a kid?

Tags: nurarihyon-no-mago

---

### Lord Second Era

As seen in Episode Number 8, during Gyuki's flashback, Yuki Onna can be seen as a woman with both adult facial feature and height.

[image: Yuki Onna Tall]

---

### Lord Third Era (Now, Episode 1-...)

Now, Yuki Onna is as tall as human form of Sandaime and has kid-like facial feature, which **is kawai :D.**

[image: Yuki Onna short]

---

## **HOW COULD THIS HAPPEN?**

NOTE: I am asking HOW not WHY

---

Although unrelated, the reason why she did this might be something like this:

> [image: unrelater]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two different Yuki Onna. The one that appears in the first picture is the mother of the one that appears in the second one. If you read the manga, it is explained in further depth there. (Sorry I forgot their names since it was a long time since I read the manga.)

Comment: Naruhodo ne! I wonder who her father is..

Comment: An old acquittance of the older Yuki Onna commented when he saw the current Yuki Onna, "Are you her daughter? No, you're her granddaughter." I forgot which episode though.

Comment: Also, the wikia entry mentioned that Tsurara (current Yuki Onna) is Setsura's (the previous Yuki Onna) daughter.